# columns in a row with space between them in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have repetitive products in a page

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
            <div class="row">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
                    {
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 order-1 d-block mb-3 cart-col " style="padding-left:10px;">
                    <section>
                        <div class="cart-title text-center w-100" >
                            <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id">  @item.Title</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id" class="d-block">

                                <img src="~/@item.ImageSrc">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="cart-title">price: 
                            <span class="cart-title">
                                @item.Price.ToString("n0")
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
                    }
            </div>
        </div>
```

it makes something like this

[image]

but I want to have margin between each book, the starting and ending book position are goods but there should be space between each column of book. if i set

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 order-1 d-block mb-3 cart-col " style="padding-left:10px;">

to
```

it would change to
[image]

how can i keep for in each row but space between each column?

this is the css:

```
.cart-col {
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #e2efef;
box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-bottom:15px;
```

}

Comment: Can you share css of .cart-col, Make div.cart-col inside .col-* div

Comment: @VIKESIR: I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bootstrap col has padding from left and right.
If it not coming, mean you defined some padding in cart-col class.
So, try this->

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="cart-col">

    </div>
</div>
```

If you need space like margin-buttom, Put gy-4 in row class.
Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

`cart-col` div should be inside `<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 order-1 d-block mb-3">`

Please replace this code by

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
        {
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 order-1 d-block mb-3">
            <div class="cart-col">
                <section>
                    <div class="cart-title text-center w-100">
                        <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id"> @item.Title</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id" class="d-block">

                            <img src="~/@item.ImageSrc">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cart-title">price:
                        <span class="cart-title">
                            @item.Price.ToString("n0")
                        </span>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `justify-content-between` class from Bootstrap on with your `flex`. So just add it as a class with a div on the `row`. I would also change `col-lg-3` to `col-lg-2` so that four-row items arent forced to take full width.

```css
.cart-col {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e2efef;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-12 order-1 d-block mb-3 cart-col " style="padding-left:10px;">
      <section>
        <div class="cart-title text-center w-100">
          <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id">  @item.Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id" class="d-block">

            <img src="~/@item.ImageSrc">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="cart-title">price:
          <span class="cart-title">
                                @item.Price.ToString("n0")
                            </span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-12 order-1 d-block mb-3 cart-col " style="padding-left:10px;">
      <section>
        <div class="cart-title text-center w-100">
          <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id">  @item.Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id" class="d-block">

            <img src="~/@item.ImageSrc">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="cart-title">price:
          <span class="cart-title">
                                @item.Price.ToString("n0")
                            </span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-12 order-1 d-block mb-3 cart-col " style="padding-left:10px;">
      <section>
        <div class="cart-title text-center w-100">
          <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id">  @item.Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id" class="d-block">

            <img src="~/@item.ImageSrc">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="cart-title">price:
          <span class="cart-title">
                                @item.Price.ToString("n0")
                            </span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-12 order-1 d-block mb-3 cart-col " style="padding-left:10px;">
      <section>
        <div class="cart-title text-center w-100">
          <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id">  @item.Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href="~/products/detail/@item.Id" class="d-block">

            <img src="~/@item.ImageSrc">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="cart-title">price:
          <span class="cart-title">
                                @item.Price.ToString("n0")
                            </span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```